# Deserialize a JSON object Inside of an Array/Square brackets

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api, asp.net-core

I am trying to consume API receiving JSON objects. The problem is my API sends these objects nested in square brackets, which makes me deseralize it as a List instead of a single object.

I am declaring this variable as an array of this instance of the class.

```
SomeModel[] variable = new SomeModel[1];

using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://someurl.dev.local/getInfo/" + id))
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            variable = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeModel[]>(apiResponse);
                                                       
                        }
                        else
                            ViewBag.StatusCode = response.StatusCode;
                    }
                }
```

Thiis is a sample of a JSON object I should be receiving, which I tested using Postman:

```
[
 {
    "pri_key": "7005210446", //concatenation of this_nbr & that_nbr
    "dl_load_date": "2021-11-25T00:00:00Z",
    "this_nbr": 7005210,
    "that_nbr": 446,
    "Passtest": "Eligible"
 }
]
```

...And this is SomeModel class:

```
    namespace ThisSolution.Models
{
    public partial class SomeModel
    {
        public DateTime? DlLoadDate { get; set; }
        public int? ThisNbr{ get; set; }
        public int? ThatNbr { get; set; }
        public string Passtest { get; set; }
        public string PriKey { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am getting is this error:

> JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.

How can I deserialize or is something wrong in my code?

Comment: You should post json  and  somemodel class.

Comment: `apiResponse` might contain html and not json.

Comment: Paste the response

Comment: @Serge I just edited the question and added json and SomeModel class. Thank you

Comment: @ScottyD0nt I've been testing this API with Postman and it is sending json objects, not html.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli you mean the json? It's in the question. I just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your model

```
public partial class SomeModel
{
    [JsonProperty("pri_key")]
    public string PriKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dl_load_date")]
    public DateTimeOffset DlLoadDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("this_nbr")]
    public int? ThisNbr { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("that_nbr")]
    public int? ThatNbr { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Passtest")]
    public string Passtest { get; set; }
}
```